# Помощь с привязкой данных в DataGrid

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, сериализация, десериализация

Xaml разметка

```
<PivotItem Header="Пользователи">
    <controls:DataGrid x:Name="usersList" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Users2List}">
    </controls:DataGrid>
</PivotItem>
```

Требуется произвести десериализацию в DataGrid с помощью конструкции показанной далее:

```
public class Users2
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String Login { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }

    public Users2(String firstName, String login, String password)
    {
    this.FirstName = firstName;
    this.Login = login;
    this.Password = password;
    }
}

public List<Users2> Users2List;
```

Есть метод, который десериализует список пользователей.

```
async void UnloadUsers()
{
    StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("Users.xml");
    Stream stream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
    List<Users> users = new List<Users>();
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Users>));
    users = (List<Users>)xml.Deserialize(stream);
    foreach (Users users1 in users)
    {
         Users2List = new List<Users2> { new Users2(users1.firstName, users1.login, users1.password) };
         }   
    }
```

Думаю не правильно написал следующую строку кода.
`Users2List = new List<Users2> { new Users2(users1.firstName, users1.login, users1.password) };`

Буду рад дополнить и ответить на ваши вопросы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решением оказалось заново присвоить DataGrid свойство ItemsSource

```
usersList.ItemsSource = Users2List;
```

Отрезок кода из метода void UnloadUsers()

```
users = (List<Users>)xml.Deserialize(stream);
Users2List = new List<Users2>();
foreach (Users users1 in users)
{
    Users2List.Add(new Users2(users1.firstName, users1.login, users1.password));
}

usersList.ItemsSource = Users2List;
```

Comment: Ну, круто, что всё получилось!

Answer (score 1):

Да, похоже, Вы правильно определили ошибку.

Похоже, что правильно было бы так:

```
users = (List<Users>)xml.Deserialize(stream);
Users2List = new List<Users2>();
foreach (Users users1 in users)
    Users2List.Add(new Users2(users1.firstName, users1.login, users1.password));
```

Comment: Код работает, но ничего в DataGrid не выводится. Параметр AutoGenerateColumns="true" стоит. Привзяка - ItemsSource="{x:Bind Users2List}". Что мне стоит проверить?

Comment: Хм, возможно, нужно что то вроде вызова метода RefreshData() у экземпляра DataGrid'а. Вообще, data binding - это не особо очевидная вещь. У некотрых DataGrid есть свойство DataSource, которому можно присвоить значение Users2List - это должно практически полностью заменять data binding